# How start broadcast from prefrence to Activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

How send broadcast from prefrenceActivity to Activity.prefrenceActivity used for reset data of other activity.

In prefrenceActivity, there is  a preference, when user click it a alert box open.If select yes then i want to start broadcast.

**Code in Activity for receive broadcast**

```
 private BroadcastReceiver objResettedReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(" broadCast receiver.      .      "+intent);

         inc = 0;
         initObjects();

    }
};
```

**register broadcast on Resume**

```
     IntentFilter localIntentFilter2 = new IntentFilter(SettingsActivity.broadcastAction);
     this.registerReceiver(this.objResettedReceiver, localIntentFilter2);
```

**unregiseter On pause & destroy Activity**

```
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    unregisterReceiver(objResettedReceiver);
    super.onPause();

}


   protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    unregisterReceiver(objResettedReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();

    System.out.println("hi.. Activity Destroy.......");
}
```

**Start broadcast**

```
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setAction(broadcastAction);
  sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Why don't you use sharepreferencechangelistener

Comment: @Tarun because we not change prefrence.Here when click on prefrence then alert box show.If select yes then activity will reset otherwise not

Comment: @Tarun can you explore more?

Comment: Make sure that the `broadcastAction` variable is unique. And what is your problem here exactly? Do you experience a problem or you just cannot receive the broadcast?

Comment: I have no error.I cannot receive broadcast.Message not print in broadcast receiver method. declare as action, public static String broadcastAction="com.fishing.reset";